# Shutting windows down hackishly

Tags: windows, shutdown

What if, by some turn of events, I lose `shutdown.exe` from my windows machine. How, then, does windows shutdown? Is it possible to put together a rough hack that does not require `shutdown.exe` but is also run from the command line? Perhaps PowerShell or .NET could help. I do have the ability to compile some C if need be.

Not that I have lost `shutdown.exe`, no. It is "Blocked by group policy"; probably due to the fact that people can and have use `shutdown -i` to use remote shutdown.

Comment: why not use ExitWindowsEx API ?

Comment: Work with your system administrator to get a policy exception. Hacking around policy is just going to get you into more trouble.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to copy "shutdown.exe" to "shutdown.scr" . Can't test it. Good Luck !

Comment: Since when are screensavers executed? On another note, making a copy might work... maybe.

Comment: perhaps you should try it before u vote down and comment

Comment: Yes! copying it did help - I copied it to the desktop and it worked! I will vote up, but I am still curious as to the alternatives.